# FOSUserBundle : Translations unreachable

Tags: symfony, translation, fosuserbundle

I'm facing an issue I can't seem to solve by myself:

We're currently working on a project using FOSUserBundle under Symfony 2.3.

It seems that one of my coworker messed up with the default FOSUser Dictionnary. Everytime we try to call any of the usual messages, either we get an empty result, or simply the value we've called (e.g registration.flash.user_created)

I've been able to locate the "wording" files under

`vendor/friendofsymfony..../translations/xxxx.en.yml`

But these files seem to have been overriden.

I don't have much code to provide regarding this issue. My only question is : Does anyone of you know what could have been done (and in which file) in order to override FOS standard dictionnaries?

With this information, I should be able to revert the settings back to normal and hopefully get the default behavior.

(Since I have no idea which file is relevant or not in this case, just tell me what info you need and I'll update my post)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Check out `app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/translations/FOSUserBundle.en.yml`. Does it exist?

Comment: In app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/ I only have "views"

Comment: Okay, now in your `app/config/config.yml` is the `translator` line enabled? Should look something like `translator:    { fallback: "%locale%" }` or `en` in place of `%locale%`

Comment: That would work only if my problem was translation-related. Unfortunately I get this problem everytime I call any of this bundle message

Comment: You said yourself you found the "wording" files under a `translations` folder. So, logically, it would make sense to ensure your translator is enabled. Can you please enable the line and confirm?

Comment: still the same error when setting `translator: { fallback: fr }` I only get the value registration.flash.user_created (which is correctly defined in FOS YAML)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63420/discussion-between-sjagr-and-wattever).